# Jquery: Finding Element In DIV

Tags: jquery

I have the following (basically, `schedule_box` is the wrapper, and there can be as many `client_schedule` divs as needed). I have `.details` hidden by default, and I want the `details` to show when the down arrow is clicked:

```
<div class="schedule_box">
    <div class="client_schedule">
        <span class="edit"> 
            <img src="images/manage_companies/down-icon.png" class="down">
        </span>
        <span class="details">
            test
        </span>
    </div>
   <div class="client_schedule">
        <span class="edit"> 
            <img src="images/manage_companies/down-icon.png" class="down">
        </span>
        <span class="details">
            test
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JQuery** (when I use the entire contact box, it works):

```
$('.schedule_box').find('.details').hide().end().find('.down').click(function() {
}
```

But, when I try to use `.down`, it's having problems finding `.details`:

```
$('.schedule_box').find('.details').hide().end().find('.down').click(function() {
     var details = $(this).find('.details');
     if (details.is(':visible')) {
         details.slideUp();
     } else {
         details.slideDown();
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
var details = $(this).parents('.client_schedule').find('.details');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `find` in the context of appropriate `".client_schedule"` parent div:

```
var details = $(this).parent('.client_schedule').find('.details');
```

That's because `this` inside click event handler is the image being clicked -- and obviously it doesn't have `".details"` div as its descendant. Its parent `".client_schedule"` div, on the other hand, has.

Answer (score 0):

You want to find the next sibling of the parent of `.down`:

```
var details = $(this).parent().next();
```

Alternatively, you could go all the way up to `.client_schedule` and find `.detail`:

```
var details = $(this).closest(".client_schedule").find(".detail");
```

**Note:** You want to use `.closest()` with this approach and not `.parent()` or `.parents()`.  `.parent()` retrieves only the immediate parent, and `.parents()` ought to have been named `.ancestors()` because it retrieves every ancestor that matches the selector.  `.closest()` gives you the first ancestor that matches the selector.

Answer (score 0):

You could always do a little event delegation by assigning the handler directly to `.client_schedule` elements, and testing what was clicked.

```
$('.client_schedule').click(function( e ) {

    if( $(e.target).is('img.down') ) {
         var details = $(this).find('.details');
         if (details.is(':visible')) {
             details.slideUp();
         } else {
             details.slideDown();
         }
    }

}).find('.details').hide();
```

---

You can also use the [`slideToggle()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) method to reduce the code a little:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/REJ6Z/

```
$('.client_schedule').click(function( e ) {

    if( $(e.target).is('img.down') ) {
         $(this).find('.details').slideToggle();
    }

}).find('.details').hide();
```